# Electron Forge with Webpack getting "require is not defined" when importing 'events'

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-forge

I've recently started a new project with electron forge and the webpack template. I'm creating a simple class for authentication and want to use the event system in nodejs. I'm using the import syntax but getting an error saying that require is undefined. I do not wish to turn on `nodeIntegration` and I thought webpack would automatically use the browserfy version of the nodejs event system:

> You usually do not have to install events yourself! If your code runs in Node.js, events is built in. If your code runs in the browser, bundlers like browserify or webpack also include the events module.

Installing the browserify event module does not fix the issue either. I also tried excluding the `node_modules/events` folder to hope webpack would use its own events module but that didn't work for me. Here is my code:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

export default class Auth {
  constructor(socket) {
  }

  setToken(token) {
    this.token = token;
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    this.emit('token', token);
  }

  checkToken() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("token") !== null) {
      this.setToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    } else {
      this.emit('false', false);
    }
  }

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem("token");
  }

  setAuth(auth) {
    this.emit('auth', auth);
    this.isAuth = auth;
  }
  
}
```

Here is my webpack renderer config:

```js
const rules = require('./webpack.rules');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
});

const assets = [ 'assets' ];
const copyPlugins = assets.map((asset) => {
  return new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    patterns: [{ from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/renderer/', asset), to: asset }],
  });
});

module.exports = {
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: 'jquery',
      }),
      ...copyPlugins
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/renderer/components'),
      'pages': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/renderer/pages'),
      'core': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/renderer/core'),
    },
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
};
```

Here is my webpack rules config:

```js
module.exports = [
  // Add support for native node modules
  {
    test: /\.node$/,
    use: 'node-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: '@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
      },
    },
  },
];
```

And here is the error:

```
external "events":
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.events (external "events":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:832)
    at fn (bootstrap:129)
    at Module../src/renderer/core/Auth.js (Auth.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:832)
    at fn (bootstrap:129)
    at Module../src/renderer/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:832)
    at fn (bootstrap:129)
    at Object.0 (routes.js:40)
```

Answer (score 2):

After taking a break from it, I realized the solution was simple:

I just needed to add the following to my renderer config:

```
target: 'web'
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail. the `;` is confusing me in particular. I added this to the module.exports with a comma but then get an error `Cannot find module 'fs'
` when I try to `require("electron")`

Comment: You are right, that should be a comma not a ;

As for your issue with fs, by putting webpack into the target web mode, there needs to be a web compiled version of it. Theres no way to use fs in the browser, so theres no web version of that library. The way I got around it was requiring those kind of libraries in the electron preload script. That said, thats just my understanding of it and this might not be totally correct so take it with a grain of salt. Thats just how I fixed my issue.

Comment: It does look like there are some wrappers for fs that might work if thats your only node library giving you issues: https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-fs

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using the `ContextBridge` API from `electron` for the electron-forge webpack template

preload.js

```
import { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } from "electron";

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {
  notificationApi: {
    sendNotification(message) {
      ipcRenderer.send("notify", message);
    },
  },
  batteryApi: {},
  fileApi: {},
});
```

main.js

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    },
 });

ipcMain.on("notify", (_, message) => {
   new Notification({ title: "Notification", body: message }).show();
});
```

package.json

```
 "plugins": [
    [
      "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
      {
        "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
        "renderer": {
          "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
          "entryPoints": [
            {
              "html": "./src/index.html",
              "js": "./src/renderer.js",
              "name": "main_window",
              "preload": {
                "js": "./src/preload.js"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
```

then using the below code will invoke the native notification message

```
electron.notificationApi.sendNotification("Finally!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when using electron forge webpack template. I found the reason is `@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader` in webpack config. After remove this loader for render, everything is OK. It seems that `@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader` should only use in node environment.